# Config file with array loaded from function in bash

Tags: bash, config

I am having the following bash file which I use as configuration:

```
# config
servers=(
    [vagrant.host]=192.168.20.20
    [vagrant.port]=22
    [vagrant.user]=ubuntu
    [vagrant.identity]=~/.ssh/id_rsa
    [vagrant.cwd]=/home/ubuntu/website
)
```

and I load it from my main script using:

```
declare -A servers
. config

echo "${servers["vagrant.host"]}" # prints 192.168.20.20
```

If the code is not in a function it works great, but I don't need the config file always loaded and I put the loading code in a function. When I call the function like shown below I receive an error.

```
function loadConfig {
    declare -A servers
    . config
}

loadConfig

echo "${servers["vagrant.host"]}" 
# vagrant.host: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".host")
```

I have no idea what is causing the error and Google didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associative arrays are *local* scope by default, make it global by adding the `-g` flag

```
declare -Ag servers
```

[The declare builtin command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare)

> -g
>   create **global** variables when used in a shell function; otherwise ignored (by default, declare declares *local* scope variables when used in shell functions)

Running the same script with the obvious script in debugger mode, produced me this,

```
$ bash -x mainscript.sh
+ loadConfig
+ declare -Ag servers
+ . config
++ servers=([vagrant.host]=192.168.20.20 [vagrant.port]=22 [vagrant.user]=ubuntu [vagrant.identity]=~/.ssh/id_rsa [vagrant.cwd]=/home/ubuntu/website)
+ echo 192.168.20.20
192.168.20.20
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `declare -g` is straigforward and easy.

But it also causes pollution by global variables. In cases here you want to use your `config` and don't want global variables, you can define the variable at the function call, like:

```
function loadConfig {
    declare -n main="$1"    # needs bash 4.3 - create an reference to indirect name
    declare -A servers      # the array name used in the config (local only)
    . ./conf
    # copy the array to indrectly aliased array...
    for key in "${!servers[@]}"
    do
        main["$key"]="${servers["$key"]}"
    done
}

#MAIN
declare -A currservers  #declare your current array
loadConfig currservers  #pass its name to loadConfig

echo "${currservers['vagrant.host']}"
# 192.168.20.20
```

Unfortunately, this needs reasonable new `bash` version `4.3+`.

Comment: `++` for demonstrating the `declare -n` approach!

Comment: Bash 4.3 is not an option and recently I found that macOS is coming with bash 3.2 and I moved to flat variables to support it.

Comment: @IvanDokov that's ok for your real project. From the pure question's point of view (e.g. sourcing assoc array in the function) it is a working solution.